# R ImageMagick. How to fill subset of image a single color

Tags: r, imagemagick

I am trying to take an image, and based on previous data, make a small square (for example top left corner at 100,100 with width,height of 50x50) all white, and the rest of the image black.

The function image_fill only takes a point, so it does not do what I am looking for.
The function image_modulate with brightness levels 0 or 100 and saturation level 0 would work, but it seems that it applies the filter to the whole image.

It seems modifying the image isn't totally necessary. I could create a separate image that is all black with a white square in the appropriate spot.

See attached image as an example I want to turn one of my regular pictures into.

Note, because of faulty alpha values in my original images, the package "imager" does not work and I must use ImageMagick (R).

[image: Example Subset Fill].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I do not know Rmagick, but in ImageMagick command line you can do that as follows. Fill the image with black. Then draw a white square where desired.

Input:

[image]

```
convert lena.png -fill black -colorize 100 -fill white -draw "rectangle 100,100 150,150" -alpha off result.png
```

Result:

[image]

The above draws the white rectangle at offset of 100,100 and width=height=50.

Alternately, you can fill the image with black, then create a new white image that is 50x50 and composite it over the black image at 100,100.

```
convert lena.png -fill black -colorize 100 -size 50x50 xc:white -gravity northwest -geometry +100+100 -compose over -composite result2.png
```

Result2:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help, after seeing your code I found the analogs I did not know/think about in RMagick. The following code worked for me:


`
img <- image_read(file)

img2 <- image_modulate(img,brightness=0,saturation=0)

img2dr <- image_draw(img2)

rect(50,50,100,100,col="white",border=NA)

dev.off()

`

Then I can save off `img2dr` to get the final result.

Comment: Yes, modulate to desaturate (set saturation to 0) and set brightness to 0 would give a black image. Good thinking. But I suspect there is also the equivalent of -fill and -colorize in RMagick. But there are often many ways to achieve the same result.